# Extract nested JSON values

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out on how to convert the following JSON object in to a dataframe

```
[
   {
      "id":"123",
      "sources":[
         {
            "name":"ABC",
            "first":"2020-02-26T03:19:23.247Z",
            "last":"2020-02-26T03:19:23.247Z"
         },
         {
            "name":"XYZ",
            "first":"2020-02-26T03:19:23.247Z",
            "last":"2020-02-26T03:19:23.247Z"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

---

```
The dataframe should appear like this.
id       ABC.first         ABC.last        XYZ.first                 XYZ.last
123      2020-02-26..      2020-02-26..   2020-02-26..  2020-02-26T03:19:23.247Z
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You may find the article [Convert nested dictionary into flattened dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-nested-dictionary-into-flattened-dictionary/) helpful.

Comment: @AMC- I understand, I did a poor job on framing my question.

Comment: @martineau- Will check it out..

Answer (score 0):

Python includes the useful `json` module. You can find some documentation for it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).

To use it , you'll need to import it into your Python script using the `import json` command.

From there, you can use the `json.loads()` method and pass it a some JSON. The `loads()` method returns a [Python dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) which then lets you access the properties of your JSON object by name. Some example code might look like:

```py
import json

# some JSON:
personJSON = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York", "address": {"street": "Fake Street", "streetNumber": "123"}}'

# parse personJSON:
personDict = json.loads(personJSON)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(personDict["name"]) # Will print "John"
print(personDict["address"]["street"]) # Will print "Fake Street"
```

Good luck!